# Timeline go to last frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to make my timeline go to last frame and just pause there? I know there is `PlayableDirector.time` but I want my script to automatically find out the last frame of the timeline. How do I do this?

```
using UnityEngine.Playables;

public PlayableDirector currentTimeline;

void Start(){
  currentTimeline.time = 0; //Go to last frame
  currentTimeline.Pause();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
currentTimeline.time = 0;
```

actually goes to the first frame and if I understand you correctly you probably rather want

```
currentTimeline.time = currentTimeline.duration;
```